# How to use values of session variables in html tags

Tags: php, session-state

The session variable is `$_SESSION['email']` which has a value XYZ , i want it to be printed inside the  `<a>` tag.
How can i print the value of the session variable inside the a tag.

```
 <?php
        session_start();
        <div class="container-fluid" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/1600x400/?travel');background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 50vh;">
                <div class=" row bg-light" style="position:fixed;width:100%;">
                    <!---NAVBAR-->
                    <ul class="nav myHeader" style="font-size:larger;">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-right:1100px;font-size :25px;" href="#">Travellelo</a>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#mymodel">Login</button>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Offers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true"><?php 
                                        if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
                                        {
                                           //here the session variable is $_SESSION['email'] = XYZ 
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                        ?>
                                            USER
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                               </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
             </div>
        ?>
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense to begin with, you can not just mix PHP and HTML like you are doing in what you have currently shown (unless you were using HHVM instead of PHP, or something like that, but that is probably not the case here.) And what is your actual question even - how to use `echo` inside an if/else block …?

Comment: simple echo like  `<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['email']))  ? $_SESSION['email'] : 'USER' ?>`

Comment: thanks Semone Rossaini , it worked )

Comment: Session really is no different to any other array in this scenario, you can echo items from it just like normal. Why was this confusing for you? I'm intrigued.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
   ?>
    <a href="test.php"><?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></a>
   <?php
}
```